# Diablo 3 Adventure Mode Act 1-5 not saving

Tags: diablo-iii

I completed ACT 1, 2, & 3 and received the reward for completing all 3 Acts. When I went in just now to start Act 4, I noticed that it’s showing Act 1-5 needs to be completed. It literally wiped out all my work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

This is how Adventure mode is intended to work. Unlike the story mode, you are not completing a set of objectives which remain consistent over time. Adventure mode provides a new set of bounties per act every time you play. For a more story-based experience where you complete acts over time with consistent progress, you would need to be playing campaign mode.

You can read more about the various modes on [the Diablo 3 website](https://us.diablo3.com/en/game/guide/gameplay/game-modes).